# Are there sahih hadith giving instructions on how to pray or whether to raise or fold your hands when praying?

Tags: salat, hadith

I am from a sect of madheheb called [Ibadhi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibadi) from Oman.  I am curious to know if there are any teachings of the Prophet on how to pray, or instructions from the Prophet when you pray to raise your hands or when you pray fold your hands?  (As opposed to hadith which claim I saw the Prophet doing this and that.)

Keep in mind a lot of hadiths are fabricated, so I want a sahih hadith only please.

Comment: Salaam and welcome to the site. Who do you think determines which hadith is sahih given that this is a controversial subject across different sects?

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about this site and model I strongly recommend you to take our 2 min. [tour] and check our [help].

Comment: From the sunni perspective I would invite you to read the ahadith in the related chapters  of Muwatta' Malik http://sunnah.com/malik as Imam a-shafi'i or Ahmad when asked how many ahadith of ahkam are there he said 500 and some and when asked how much of it is in al-Muwatta' he answered 500 so any narration there in which ends as a saying or doing of the Prophet is accepted as sahih and you wil find it in any other sunni hadith collection!

Comment: i think the best book in the chapter of salat is the book of nasir-eddin alalbany 
صفة صلاة النبي صلى الله عليه و سلم 
english : https://islamhouse.com/ar/books/1273/
arabic: http://www.archive.org/stream/waq101315/101315#page/n7/mode/2up